# Discrete form of deformation gradient from vectors with finite length

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics

I am writing some code for a deformable mesh and need to calculate a local deformation gradient within the material by using the vectors connecting material points. I think the method of solving should resemble the figure below:
[image]

The deformation gradient is then defined as the matrix that maps the undeformed vector (dx) to the deformed vector (dy): 
Since my model has discrete lengths between the material points, the partial derivates are replaced with $\Delta$. However when I try implementing the formulas, I do not get a deformation matrix that maps dx to dy.

As a simple example, I consider a vector dx with components in the e1 and e2 directions [1 1], and the deformed vector with components [2 1], and deformation vectors at the end points of dx as u(x) and u(x+dx) to have components [0 0] and [1 0], respectively.
[image]

But when I multiply F (deformation matrix) times dx, I don't get dy. dy is [2 1] but F*dx gives [3 1].

I don't understand how I am incorrectly implementing a discrete version of the deformation gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is not with your code? If it is I would need to see that to offer any help. Also, I am not very familiar with deformation, but if this gradient operation is the same as a vector gradient ($\nabla$) there is a nice paper by C. Bommaraju titled *Investigating Finite Volume Time Domain Methods in Computational Electromagnetics*. In the paper he/she goes through various discretizations of vector calculus operations and one of them is the gradient. At the end there is a fully discrete formula. This particular paper is for electromagnetics but like I said if you're talking about a vector gradient ($\nabla V$) then it should apply just as well.

Comment: I have't actually implemented the code yet. I have just been performing the math using simple examples. I have taken a look at the paper that you mention and check others covering discrete vector calculus, however I am still not sure of the error.

Comment: okay I am going through trying to find an error but so far nothing. Can you quickly define what *U* is? That will help a bit

Comment: U is the displacement vector.

Comment: Seems to me that your analysis is correct, I am not sure why it's yielding an incorrect answer. The only thing I can think of is revise the formula or search for the formula in another textbook/article because every once in a while there are typos that slip by.

Answer (score 0):

Denoting ${\bf dx} = {\bf b}- {\bf a}$, what you have is
$$ 
dy_i = dx_i + \Delta U_i
$$
or explicitly,
$$
y_i({\bf b}) - y_i({\bf a}) = [b_i - a_i] + [U_i({\bf b}) - U_i({\bf a})]
$$
which checks out fine. But what you need is 
$$
\Delta U_i \equiv U_i({\bf b}) = \sum_j{ \frac{\partial U_i}{\partial x_j}({\bf b}) dx_j}
$$
where $U_i({\bf a}) = 0$. The trouble is that with the gradient as you defined it this sum gives
$$
\sum_j{ \frac{U_i({\bf b}) - U_i({\bf a})}{b_j - a_j}  (b_j - a_j)}  = \sum_j{[U_i({\bf b}) - U_i({\bf a})]} \neq U_i({\bf b})
$$

Here's the reason: your gradient amounts to 
$$
 \frac{U_i({\bf b}) - U_i({\bf a})}{b_j - a_j} =  \frac{U_i(b_1, b_2) - U_i(a_1, a_2)}{b_j - a_j} 
$$
But look at the arguments of $U$: those do not work for a partial derivative, because by definition the partial must be taken along the direction of the differential in the denominator!
So let's try instead
$$
\frac{U_i(b_1, b_2) - U_i(a_1, b_2)}{b_1- a_1}  (b_1 - a_1) + \frac{U_i(a_1, b_2) - U_i(a_1, a_2)}{b_2 - a_2}(b_2 - a_2) = \\
U_i(b_1, b_2) - U_i(a_1, b_2) + U_i(a_1, b_2) - U(a_1, a_2) \equiv U_i({\bf b}) 
$$
Now this works fine, **at a price**: you also need the $U_i$-s at the intermediate point $(a_1, b_2)$, where you haven't defined them yet. In other words, you need each of the differentials $\Delta U_i$ along 2 orthogonal directions in order to calculate the gradient, not just $\Delta U_i$-s between the points of interest $\bf a$, $\bf b$.